# Venn Diagram Drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I am preparing a presentation in Beamer. I want to draw a Venn diagram within a Venn diagram within a Venn diagram :D. I mean three circles from biggest to the smallest where the biggest one encompasses the other two, and the smallest one is the intersecting area of the all three. I use Tikz package. I am new with the Latex. So I could really use some help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you provide a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to show what you have tried?

Comment: There is a `venndiagram` package that should allow you to draw that. (There is also `pst-venn` but since you are using `beamer` that may not be your first choice.)

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9681/how-to-draw-venn-diagrams-especially-complements-in-latex with various different approaches that can get you started.

Comment: Or https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=2rvg for an example with nesting.

Comment: The first circle encompasses the other two, so the second one is inside the first one. The third is the intersection of 1 and 2, so coincides with 2. Seems strange to me. Could you provide use with a cartoon that shows what you are after?

Comment: See this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101706/venn-diagram-with-tikz?rq=1, possibly filling the circles with different colors.

Comment: Thank you all, I gave a break. This is why I could not turn back to check the comments here. I believe the links above will help me. And sorry for the confusion I basically wanted to draw "A ⊂ B ⊂ C" with this formal expression it may be clear more.